# How to link to a file type search on GitHub?

Tags: github

On this pull request https://github.com/github/linguist/pull/3208 the Original Poster added some file search links for `.nsi` and `.awk` file types:

[image]

How did he do that? Is there some special syntax like `@mention` or `user/repo#issue` or he just did it the hard way:

```
[`.nsi` files](https://github.com/search?p=5&q=extension%3Ansi+if&ref=searchresults&type=Code&utf8=%E2%9C%93)
[`.awk` files](https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=extension%3Aawk+if&type=Code&ref=searchresults)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not aware of any magic syntax for searches. Certainly nothing appears in the [Mastering Markdown guide](https://guides.github.com/features/mastering-markdown/) or the [basic writing and formatting syntax page](https://help.github.com/articles/basic-writing-and-formatting-syntax/), though both describe user mentions, issue links, SHA links, etc.

I would speculate that the author of that comment performed a search in another tab, then copied the generated URL to their comment.